# BCDedit on Windows 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012, bcdedit

The first boot entry that comes up on this machine is hosed.  The second is good.  However, I can't figure out how to delete the bad one- they all seem to share the same identifier.  Anybody have any suggestions on how to fix?  Output of `bcdedit /v` below.

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {9dea862c-5cdd-4e70-acc1-f32b344d4795}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {7ea2e1ac-2e61-4728-aaa3-896d9d0a9f0e}
bootshutdowndisabled    Yes
default                 {2f62c409-2b6e-11e4-8674-9b5475bb064b}
resumeobject            {2f62c408-2b6e-11e4-8674-9b5475bb064b}
displayorder            {2f62c409-2b6e-11e4-8674-9b5475bb064b}
                        {2f62c403-2b6e-11e4-8674-9b5475bb064b}
                        {2f62c3ff-2b6e-11e4-8674-9b5475bb064b}
toolsdisplayorder       {b2721d73-1db4-4c62-bf78-c548a880142d}
timeout                 3

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {2f62c409-2b6e-11e4-8674-9b5475bb064b}
device                  unknown
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows Server
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {6efb52bf-1766-41db-a6b3-0ee5eff72bd7}
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                unknown
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {2f62c408-2b6e-11e4-8674-9b5475bb064b}
nx                      OptOut

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {2f62c403-2b6e-11e4-8674-9b5475bb064b}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows Server 2012 R2
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {6efb52bf-1766-41db-a6b3-0ee5eff72bd7}
recoverysequence        {2f62c406-2b6e-11e4-8674-9b5475bb064b}
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {2f62c402-2b6e-11e4-8674-9b5475bb064b}
nx                      OptOut
hypervisorlaunchtype    Auto

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {2f62c3ff-2b6e-11e4-8674-9b5475bb064b}
device                  partition=D:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows Server 2012 R2
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {6efb52bf-1766-41db-a6b3-0ee5eff72bd7}
recoverysequence        {2f62c400-2b6e-11e4-8674-9b5475bb064b}
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=D:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {2f62c3fe-2b6e-11e4-8674-9b5475bb064b}
nx                      OptOut
hypervisorlaunchtype    Auto
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- the identifiers actually all differ by one digit (the eighth one)
- I was trying to do this in an admin Powershell.  Doing it in admin cmd works.